# Is it different between two way to call a function in an other class?

Tags: php, function, class, call

I have a class

```
<?php
class Test{
    public function printword($word){
         echo $word;
    }
}
?>
```

And in another class, i call it.

```
<?php
//Included needed files !!!
$w = 'Hello';

//Way 1
$a = new Test;
$result = $a->printword($w);

//Way 2
$result = Test::printword($w);
?>
```

Is it different ?

And 
`$a = new Test;` or `$a = new Test();` is right ?

Comment: *Is it different ?* Yes the one is wrong and the other one correct. You don't have a static method here, so you need to use `->`. *And  $a = new Test; or $a = new Test(); is right ?* Both. If you want to pass arguments to the constructor then of course you have to write the parentheses.

Comment: I use $result = Test::printword($w); and it still run ?

Comment: use public static function printword()

Comment: @Fil can you explain ?

Comment: Yes it does, but it's wrong. Turn on error reporting and you get a warning about it

Comment: @Rizier123, ok thanks a lots, i got it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's different. if you declare a method `static` makes them accessible without needing an instantiation of the class.

```
class Test{
    public function printword($word){
        echo $word;
   }
}

//Call printword method
$a= new Test();
$a->printword('Words to print');
```

**Static Method:**

```
class Test{
    public static function printword($word){
        echo $word;
   }
}

//Do not need to instantiation Test class
Test::printword('Words to print');
```

See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).

Comment: Can a ask, so do we should use all static function, because it looks simple, easy to use, and  do not need to instantiation ?

Comment: Actually, No, use a static method when it's complete itself and not depended to others properties of the class (like, for instance, a syntax converter for BB code to HTML)